# Direct sum of modules, modules homomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If $V, U$ are $k$-vector spaces and $f : V \rightarrow U$ a surjective linear map, we know that $V / \operatorname{Ker}(f) \cong U$ and $V \cong \operatorname{Ker}(f) \oplus U$. My question is: if $M, N$ are $R$-modules and $f : M \rightarrow N$ a surjective linear map of modules, is it also true that $N$ is a direct summand of $M$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is false in general.

For instance, a quotient $R/I$ of $R$ by an ideal $I$ is (isomorphic to) a direct summand of $R$ if & only if  $I$ is generated by an idempotent $e$  and its supplement is generated by $1-e$.

Also  if $f:M\longrightarrow N$ is surjective and if $N$ is a *projective* $R$-module (i.e. a direct summand of a free $R$-module), then $N$ is indeed isomorphic to a direct summand of $N$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $R=\mathbb Z$ and $M\longrightarrow N$ given by projecting $\mathbb Z/p^2$ onto $\mathbb Z/p$. This cannot split (meaning, you cannot have $\mathbb Z/p$ as a direct summand) since this would imply all elements in $\mathbb Z/p^2$ are of order $p$.